# Nav background image 100% height of page

Tags: css, html, navigation, background-image, nav

I'm trying to get the navigation background image to be the same height as my page and I can't figure out how. I have tried a bunch of different things found on this site to no avail. I'm very new to HTML5 and CSS so apologies if this is a stupid question. Here is my CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #FF9933;
}
header {
    background-image: url(orangesquares.png);
}
h1 {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    opacity: 0.6;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 275px
}
h2 {
    color: #FF9933;
}
nav {
    background-image: url(orangesquares.png);
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 0;
    Margin-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    opacity: 0.6;
    padding: 10px;
}
#rightcolumn {
    margin-left: 205px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
    width: 80%;
}
.content {
    padding: 10px 20px 0 20px;
}
#footer {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 11px;
}
a:link {
    color: #0033FF;
}
a:visited {
    color: #0033FF;
}
figure {
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid #FF9933;
    padding: 5px;
}
figcaption {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

Here is my HTML code for the index page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Sims 3 Open House</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Sims 3 Open House provides information on houses included in the Sims 3 bin, such as what furniture is included and how many squares big the rooms are." />
        <meta name="keywords" content="Sims 3, the sims 3, the sims, sims, open house, house, houses, home, homes, lots and houses bin, bin, premade, premade houses, lot size, house size, furniture" />
        <link type="text/css" href="openhouse.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>

    <body>

        <header>
            <h1>Sims 3 Open House</h1>
        </header>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li><br>
                <li><a href="index.html#onebedroom">One Bedroom Homes</a></li>
                <ul>
                    <li>Cabin Fever</li>
                    <li>Super Shack</li>
                </ul>
                <li><a href="index.html#twobedrooms">Two Bedroom Homes</a></li>
                <ul>
                    <li>Ginger</li>
                    <li>Oak Grove Bungalow</li>
                </ul>
                <li><a href="index.html#threebedrooms">Three Bedroom Homes</a></li>
                <ul>
                    <li>Cornucopia</li>
                    <li>Doubleday Lodge</li>
                </ul>
                <li>Contact Us</li>
        </nav>

        <article>
            <div id="rightcolumn">

                <div class="content"> 
                    <h2>Welcome</h2>
                    <p>Ever want to use a house from the Sims 3 bin but you aren't sure which one? What do they look like inside? How big are they really? What kind of     furniture do they have? Well, here you can find all that information! I have split the bin houses into categories by number of bedrooms to make your search easier. On each house's page there is detailed information about the layout of each house, how big the rooms are, and what furniture is included, plus general info like lot size and price. All screenshots were taken in <a    href="http://www.thesims3.com/assetDetail.html?assetId=7016943">Sunset Valley 2</a>. </p>

                    <a id="onebedroom"><h2>One Bedroom Homes</h2></a>


                    <figure>
                        <img src="cabinfever.jpg" width="500px" alt="The front facade of the home Cabin Fever." />
                        <figcaption>
                            Cabin Fever
                        </figcaption>
                        </figure> <figure>
                        <img src="supershack.jpg" width="500px" alt="The front facade of the home Super Shack." />
                        <figcaption>
                            Super Shack
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>

                    <a id="twobedrooms"><h2>Two Bedroom Homes</h2></a>

                    <figure>
                        <img src="ginger.jpg" width="500px" alt="The front facade of the home Ginger." />
                        <figcaption>
                            Ginger
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="ogb.jpg" width="500px" alt="The front facade of the home Oak Grove  Bungalow." />
                        <figcaption>
                            Oak Grove Bungalow
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>

                    <a id="threebedrooms"><h2>Three Bedroom Homes</h2></a>

                    <figure>
                        <img src="cornucopia.jpg" width="500px" alt="The front facade of the home Cornucopia." />
                        <figcaption>
                            Cornucopia
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <figure>
                        <img src="doubleday.jpg" width="500px" alt="The front facade of the home Doubleday Lodge." />
                        <figcaption>
                            Doubleday Lodge
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>

                </div>

                <br> 

                <div id="footer">
                    <footer>
                        Home | One Bedroom Homes | Cabin Fever | Super Shack | Two Bedroom Homes | Ginger | Oak Grove Bungalow | Three Bedroom homes | Cornucopia | Doubleday Lodge | Contact Us
                        <br>
                        Copyright &copy; 2015 Natasha Schmidt
                    </footer>
                </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Share your HTML code too

Answer (score 1):

why putting your bg in nav?

either make it full height

```
nav
{
background-image: url(orangesquares.png);
background-size: cover;
float: left;
height:100%
width: 200px;
margin-top: 0;
Margin-bottom: 0;
font-weight: bold;

}
```

or I don't know, do it right like

```
html{
   padding:0; margin:0;background-image: url(orangesquares.png);
background-size: cover;
}
```

and remove the background from the nav.

Comment: I just want the background to be in the nav (as well as the header, but that was pretty easy). I tried your suggestion but it didn't do anything. I did look at it with the background as the whole background rather than just in the nav and header and it looks alright, just not exactly how I wanted it. I'll probably just do that if I can't figure this out.